# Network modem question

Tags: computer-architecture, coding-theory, arithmetic

How would I solve the following can anyone help me.I know MIPS is basically how many instruction the processor can do per second but what should I do?

Assume that we are receiving a message across a network using a modem with a rate of 56,000 bits/second. Furthermore assume that we are working on a workstation with an instruction rate of 500 mips. How many instructions can the processor execute between the receipt of each individual bit of the message?

Comment: This is a question about basic arithmetics, not computer science.

Comment: I did not make it up but it was part of the homework in my intro to comp science classs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are not enough details in the question. Yuval's answer gives the basic arithmetic answer. I'll just add that usually modems do not transfer the information "as-is" but encode it (see [Asynchronous serial communication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asynchronous_serial_communication)).

The most common encoding is [8N1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/8-N-1), which means 10 symbols are sent per 1 byte of the message. The [baud rate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baud_rate) (56,000) is the number of symbols per second, rather than the number of bits per second.

So 8 bits of the message take 10 symbols, that is 1/5600 second. 1 bit takes 1/44800 sec. During that time, with 500MIPS you have $\approx 11200$ instructions.

(of course, if the rate is indeed 56000 **bits**/sec, then the 8/10 factor is not necessary.)

Comment: Wait how did you get 11 instructions I understand the other part but the 11 instructions confuses me. And ye it is 56000 bits/sec so would that change how I did my problem I just need a clear answer I am new to comp science..

Comment: 500MIPs mean 500,000,000 instructions per second. So in $t$ seconds you get $500,000,000 t$ instructions. And yes, my answer above was off by a factor of 1000. (; it's $\approx 11.2$k instructions. And for 56000bps, it's 8930 instructions, give or take.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Suppose that the processor manages to execute $N$ instructions between the receipt of each individual bit. Executing the $N$ instructions takes time $T_1$. The time interval between the receipt of each individual bit is $T_2$. Set up an inequality and solve for $N$.

Comment: so would N be 56000/500?

Comment: I don't know, you tell me. How did you get to that particular fraction? Don't guess the solution, work it through.

Comment: I do not understand how to solve this problem can you  please provide some more explanation in your hint as I am confused...